# Directly showing that a prime is unramified iff the inertia group is trivial

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Consider a Galois extension $L/K$ of number fields and denote by $B,A$ the corresponding integer rings. Let $Q$ be a prime in $B$ lying over $P$ (which is in $A$). Let $D,I$ denote the decomposition and inertia groups of $Q$ respectively. Consider the following statement:

> The following are equivalent:
>
> - $I$ is trivial,
> - $P$ is unramified in $B$.

I am looking for a proof of this statement which would be as direct as possible. I have found two different proofs of this fact, one of them contained in in Marcus's "Number Fields", and one in [these notes](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter8.pdf). Both make essential use of the $efg=n$ identity ($g$ - number of primes in $B$ lying over $P$, $n$ - degree of $L/K$) to find that $|I|=e$ after working out different numbers, e.g. $|D|$ and $|D/I|$. However, I feel like we should be able to prove this without having to do such computations. Does anyone know of such a proof?

Thanks in advance

PS. I am mostly interested in the implication "$P$ unramified" $\Rightarrow$ "$I$ trivial", so I am willing to accept an answer which provides only this single implication.

Comment: One can take $I$ being trivial as your definition for being unramified. This definition is the one that we really care about for a lot of applications (if $I$ is trivial, then the Frobenius endomorphism of the Galois group of the residue fields can be pulled back uniquely to $D$). The usefulness of the "$e,f,g$" definition is purely the fact that $efg=n$.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the crux behind the definition of the decomposition and inertia groups is as follows:

Consider the extension of fields $L/L^I/L^D/K$, where $L^D$ and $L^I$ are the fixed fields of $D$ and $I$ respectively. Then

- $P$ splits completely in $L^D$.
- Any prime $P_D$ of $L^D$ above $P$ is inert in $L^I$.
- Let $P_I$ be the prime of $L^I$ above $P_D$. Then $P_I$ is totally ramified in $L$.

In other words these groups allow us to decompose $L/K$ into totally split, totally ramified and inert extensions, allowing us to reduce our efforts to each of these three types alone.

---

We will show that $P$ is ramified in $L/L^I$ (in fact it is totally ramified). In particular, if $P$ is unramified in $L$, then $L/L^I$ must be trivial, so $I = 1$. This can be shown without assuming $efg = n$ as follows:

Let $P_I = Q\cap L^I$ be the prime of $L^I$ under $Q$. Let $D_I$ be the decomposition group of $Q/P_I$. Then our key observation is that
$$D_I=D\cap I = I = \mathrm{Gal}(L/L^I).$$

Since $D_I=\mathrm{Gal}(L/L^I)$ acts transitively on the primes above $P_I$, and it fixes $Q$, $Q$ must be the only prime of $L$ above $P_I$.

In a similar way, the inertia group of $Q/P_I$ is $I$. Since by definition, $I$ is the kernel of the map
$$D_I\to \mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb F_Q/\mathbb F_{P_I}),$$
it follows that the residue degree of $Q/P_I$ is $1$.

So $f=g=1$. At this point, if we could assume that $efg =n$, we could deduce that $Q/P_I$ is totally ramified. However, to deduce the $L/L^I$ is ramified, we only need to assume that $efg>1$, which is a much weaker fact.

---

For the converse, I think that using the fact that $efg = n$ is necessary, although I'd be interested if someone can bypass this fact.

Answer (score 1):

Recall inertia is the kernel $\mathrm{Gal}(O_K/O_k)\to \mathrm{Gal}(\kappa’/\kappa)$, inertia being trivial means this map is injective. Given homomorphisms $f_1,f_2\colon O_K\to O_K$ which have same reduction modulo $m$. Then $\overline{g}=\overline{f_1}-\overline{f_2}$ is a derivation $O_K\to m/m^2$. Unramifiedness implies this morphism is zero since $Der_{O_k}(O_k, m/m^2)=Hom(\Omega_{O_K/O_k}, m/m^2)=Hom(0,m/m^2)$ is zero. Thus $g$ maps into $m^2$ keep doing show image of $g$ has arbitraryly large valuation. Thus $g=0,f_1=f_2$.